# OOP architecture in PHP - Symfony2 application (User - Project - Task)

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I have a problem with creating an elegant architecture for my app which is written in Symfony2 framework. I want to emphasize the SF2 because I suppose that there may be framework-specific best-solution.

**The situation**

I have an application in which users can pick up projects and accomplish them. Each project has a series of tasks. When user signs up for a project, he gets first of the tasks from the project, on the next day he gets next task and so on, until there's no more tasks in the project.

The projects and tasks are created by the admin in CMS. When user succeeds/fails the task it has to be noted (status, date, user_id, etc.). Please note, that the situation is not like editing an article on the blog where there's only one instance of the article that's being modified by many users. Here the project and its tasks will not be modified because many users can sign up for one project - they all will have different results.

So I have classes: User, Project and Task.

**The question**

Basic question is: how should I record results of different users for each task and also keeps things logical and also make it nice in SF2 where the database tables are created based on classes (entites). It would be great to have an architecture that will facilitate the development: I will have to display upcomping tasks, there will be calendar, I will have to make statistic of succeeded/failed tasks and so on.

**Solution that I was able to invent**

When user signs up for a project I could create a kind of copy of all the project's tasks. They could be an objects of class UserTask and they would store all the data that are necessary for the process. So the UserTask would be a Task that belongs to the user.

Comment: It's fine to mention that this is an SF2 project, but I think it's unlikely to have any impact on it. Primarily, this is a database design question, I think, and possibly too subjective to have a definitive answer. If you agree that it's your database design that needs attention, maybe edit in the definitions of those tables? I wonder if you need more tables: if a user fails at a task, presumably it will be done again by a different user. If so, you'll need a `user_task` table to collect data about that relationship.

Comment: This is really too broad of a topic to possibly be answered here along SO guidelines.  My advice would be to think about the database architecture.  What tables are your going to need to store the data you need to store?  This will go a long way in informing your class structure, if you go with the general approach of a class representing interactions with data in a single underlying table.

Comment: So how would you, from the database perspective, solve this issue? Do you think my proposition is acceptable? Would you do the same if the project would be as simple as User-Project-Task?

Comment: Please explain if two users can work on the same task at the same moment. This looks like a waste of time if people work in parallel, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes. Let me clarify: admin sets the projects and many users can sign up to one project and gets its tasks. But user's actions cannot modify those "base" project/tasks. These are something like a prototypes. Each user have it's own results and has own shedule for the tasks (depending on when he started).